# How to interpret zero-inflation model for Bayesian regression?

Tags: regression, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, zero-inflation, bugs

I am trying to understand the zero-inflated poisson (ZIP) model used in Bayesian regression modelling. I came across code [here](https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A2=BUGS;55f0a6a0.05) for the ZIP model. My question is related to the 3rd line of code within the for loop, that is:

```
phi[i]<- -LL[i]+10000
```

I am not sure why the `10,000` is used here. For instance, when you look at appendix A for the ZIP regression Winbugs code in a paper found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sujit_Ghosh4/publication/223718586_Bayesian_analysis_of_zero-inflated_regression_models/links/59de7632458515376b29e19d/Bayesian-analysis-of-zero-inflated-regression-models.pdf), there is no use of this `10,000`. Any clarification would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the zero’s trick used to define a new sampling distributions in WinBUGS. Check the manual about defining new sampling distributions or see [here](http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/Joseph/courses/common/Tricks.html).

Comment: one more question.......as shown by the paper which does not use the '10,000', does it mean the zero trick is not always needed?

Comment: In the mathematical definition of the model you don’t need it. It’s just a trick used in WinBUGS.